# How can I accept answers to my questions?

Tags: support

Please help me increase my acceptance rate. How do I accept answers to my questions?

Comment: Belongs on Meta: http://meta.serverfault.com/

Comment: Please try to use proper English when contributing to this site. It's highly unprofessional to use abbreviations like "pls" and "qns", and this site is for professionals only (see the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Click the check box underneath the rep arrows of the answer that you would like to accept.

[image]

Image shamelessly *borrowed* from [MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)