# how to find the list of questions which i haven't make an accept?

Tags: support, site-usage

this question is different from [How do I find out if my Questions\Answers have been edited](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1117/how-do-i-find-out-if-my-questions-answers-have-been-edited) and [How can I accept answers to my questions?](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1033/how-can-i-accept-answers-to-my-questions), it's not about how to make an accept, but to show the list of questions which are not accepted:)

sometimes i may find my accept rate is a bit low, then i should navigate all the questions in order to find which questions i haven't make an accept, which is quite boring.

is there any convinent way to find the list of questions which i haven't make an accept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the questions list in your profile. The ones you haven't accepted an answer on will have the dotted rectangle around the number in a paler shade of green.

Comment: this should be wrote in the FAQ:)

Comment: It probably should but the sad fact is that almost nobody ever reads the FAQ.

Answer (score 5):

Use a search like [this](https://serverfault.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aquestion+hasaccepted%3A0&submit=search).

```
user:me is:question hasaccepted:0
```

Comment: It look almost obvious when you read it but really, who would ever have guessed? Maybe that's another gem buried too deep in all this wonderfully clear and helpful documentation the site has.

Comment: The search operations are documented on the are on the search help page which you will see after performing a search, and clicking on `See our search tips!` http://serverfault.com/search